LVM thinpools: is fragmentation a concern?
I'm currently migrating a ~10TB dataset from a plain LVM volume group to a new one, trying to store the data in a thin pool instead.
For regular LVM volumes, I could see the physical allocation of the extents on the disk with pvdisplay -m, but with a thinpool, I can only see the allocation of physical extents to the thinpool itself, not any of the volumes inside it.
Because the order in which data is written to the thinpool is non-deterministic (like if it's being done concurrently by several VMs), I'm worried about disk fragmentation, where the data corresponding to the same LV is scattered across the entire disk and needs a lot of seeking to read.
Is this a real issue with LVM thinpools? I considered that LVM could be automatically doing defragmentation in the background somehow. What info is there about how this works?
